# CakePHP – html helper how to turn off escaping?

Tags: php, cakephp

I use Cake 2.2.2, and to build a link I use HtmlHelper.

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('Link',array('controller' => 'mycontroller', 'action' => 'myAction', '3'."#map"), array('escape' => false));?>
```

I need to pass value 3 to my controller and I also need the link to have #map (html anchor).

But despite the fact that I use array('escape' => false), output appears to be escaped and #map becomes 3%23map.

Where I made a mistake? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::url

you need to use

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('Link', array(..., '#' => 'map'), ...);?>
```